# Mikrotik, Провайдер с /29 и отсутствующий DHCP?

Tags: сеть, роутер, mikrotik

День добрый, сообщество!

Имеется RB2011, провайдер без DHCP на первом порту, сервак с ESXi на втором порту. 
Задача: обеспечить виртуалки белыми айпишниками через DHCP, желательно с wire speed.
Сейчас имеем колхозиг в виде бриджа с этими двумя портами и DHCP сервером на этом бридже. Прову это не очень нравится, так как DHCP серв ему мешает.

[image: Mikrotik config]

Как посоветуете поступить?

P.S. Ну, разумеется, роутер тоже должен быть доступен извне.

Comment: Каким нибудь ACL запретить входящие с eth1 пакеты на 67 UDP порт. Для порядка можно еще запретить исходящие к провайдеру на 67/68 UDP. Либо договорится с провом что бы отдавал подсеть маршрутизацией через некие интерфейсные IP и у себя тогда делать обычную маршрутизацию вместо бриджа

Answer (score 1):

У вас шлюз провайдера и ESX в одном широковещательном домене, можно конечно попробовать запретить DHCP на первом порту, но это моветон.

Уберите бридж, сделайте Stasic NAT один к одному и раздавайте машинам серые адреса.

Comment: Это еще бОльший колхоз. Ненавижу эти три буквы: NAT.

Comment: Проблему я уже решил, спасибо MUM 2016 Slovenia. Вот [презенташка](http://mum.mikrotik.com/presentations/EU16/presentation_2959_1456526484.pdf) (слайд 50)

Comment: да, решение очень элегантное и лучше чем нат.